# problem in traversing through unordered_map cpp

Tags: c++, unordered-map

only half of the test cases pass when i traverse through unordered_map, but when i use vector all of them pass, is there any mistake in my code?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;  cin>>n;
    unordered_map<int,int> mp;
    vector<int> v;  v.reserve(n);
    while(n--)
    {
        int x,y;  cin>>x>>y;
        int h=y+x;
        if(mp[h]==0){ v.push_back(h); }
        mp[h]++;
    }
    int s; cin>>s;  int sa=0;
    for(auto i:mp)
    {
        int j=i.first+s;
        long long u=mp[j]*(i.second);
        sa=sa+u;
    }
    cout<<sa;
}
```

Comment: And what are you trying to do? BTW, this looks like [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) because of default inserted int `if(mp[h]==0)`

Comment: @pptaszni It is value initialized, no UB here.

Comment: What the test cases are testing? What is your code expected to do? What is unexpected in your code?

Answer (score 1):

In this loop:

```
for(auto i:mp)
{
    int j=i.first+s;
    long long u=mp[j]*(i.second);
    sa=sa+u;
}
```

you are potentially modifying `mp` when you do `mp[j]`, in the case that `j` is not a key in the `unordered_map`. Modifying a range that you are iterating over in a range-for loop invokes undefined behavior.

You can use `find` to check if the key `j` exists and do something else in that case (but not modify the `unordered_map`).